# Change y-axis of dot plot to reflect actual count using geom_dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a dot plot using `geom_dotplot` of `ggplot2`.

However, as shown in the examples on [this page](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_dotplot.html), the scales of y-axis range from 0 to 1. I wonder how I can change the y-axis scale so the values reflect the actual count of the data.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Comment: Basically, I am working with the example on the linked page. In the following example, y-axis doesn't mean anything.

`ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) + geom_dotplot(stackgroups = TRUE, binwidth = 1, method = "histodot")` I tried to add `+ ylim(0:42)` to specify the minimum and the maxumum count of the data, but the y-axis scale doesn't match the actual values. If you change the size of the graph, it also changes the y-axis randomly.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example which might be helpful.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggExtra)
library(dplyr)

# use the preloaded iris package in R
irisdot <- head(iris["Petal.Length"],15)
# find the max frequency (used `dplyr` package). Here n is the label for frequency returned by count().
yheight <- max(dplyr::count(irisdot, Petal.Length)["n"]) 
# basic dotplot (binwidth = the accuracy of the data)
dotchart = ggplot(irisdot, aes(x=Petal.Length), dpi = 600)
binwidth = 0.1
dotsize = 1
dotchart = dotchart + geom_dotplot(binwidth=binwidth, method="histodot", dotsize = dotsize, fill="blue")
# use coor_fixed(ratio=binwidth*dotsize*max frequency) to setup the right y axis height.
dotchart = dotchart + 
  theme_bw() + 
  coord_fixed(ratio=binwidth*dotsize*yheight)
# tweak the theme a little bit
dotchart = dotchart + theme(panel.background=element_blank(),
                            panel.border = element_blank(),
                            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                            # plot.margin=unit(c(-4,0,-4,0), "cm"),
                            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                            axis.line.y = element_blank(),
)
# add more tick mark on x axis
dotchart = dotchart + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,1.8,0.1))
# add tick mark on y axis to reflect frequencies. Note yheight is max frequency.
dotchart = dotchart + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 1), expand = c(0, 0), breaks = seq(0, 1,1/yheight), labels=seq(0,yheight))
# remove x y lables and remove vertical grid lines
dotchart = dotchart + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) + removeGridX()
dotchart
```

[image: A dotplot for 15 iris petal lengths]

I don't know why it works. It seems that the height of y axis for geom_dotplot is 1. The ratio between x and y was setup by coor_fixed(ratio=binwidth * dotsize * max frequency).

Comment: Excellent! But I do not understand the line calculating `yheight`. Doesn't `max` depend from the binwidth? --- I assigned a fixed value from my visual inspection from a histogram with the same data and parameters.

Comment: Here I assume that the binwidth is '1', because the focus is dotplot. For histogram in general, I guess there should be a similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use `geom_histogram` instead.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1)
```

The issue seem to be in that `geom_dotplot` cannot be converted to count, as seen in the github issue [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2203).